# Is it possible to constrain the values of variables in angular or typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Is it possible to constrain the values of variables?
Suppose there is a variable

```
carColor: string;
```

It can be seen that this is a string variable, and the value may be "green" or "yellow" or "pink".

But if I have a set of color arrays, I might do this:

```
export enum ENUM_Color {
  Yellow  =  'Yellow',
  Green   =  'Green',
  Pink    =  'Pink',
}

export type ColorMapping = {[key in ENUM_Color]: string};

export const ColorShowName: Readonly<ColorMapping> = {
  Yellow  : 'Banana yellow',
  Green   : 'Jungle green',
  Pink    : 'Rainbow pink',
};
```

So far, I have prepared everything I need, but the only problem is that I want to restrict the value of carColor to the range of ENUM_Color, that is, the string of carColor can only be "Yellow" or "Green" or "Pink" , Cannot be "Silver" or "Red".

Is there a way to do it? Otherwise, only specifying string as the interface is too dangerous, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and you was nearly there..

```
type CarColor = 'Yellow' | 'Green' | 'Pink';

type ColorMapping = { [key in CarColor]: string }

export const ColorShowName: Readonly<ColorMapping> = {
  Yellow  : 'Banana yellow',
  Green   : 'Jungle green',
  Pink    : 'Rainbow pink',
};
```

Try changing any of the Yellow, Green, Pink, to something incorrect, and Typescript should give you an error.

Comment: What a clever way, I didn’t expect it, haha, thanks for sharing